# $(a - a^t)e^{\frac{1}{2} a^ta^t} | 0 \rangle = 0$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators

When talking about the limits of squeezed states, we reach the conclusion that $e^{\frac{1}{2} a^ta^t} | 0 \rangle$ must be an eigenstate for momentum since the uncertainty in momentum becomes zero.

As such I would expect that $(a - a^t)e^{\frac{1}{2} a^ta^t} | 0 \rangle = 0$ if it is the zero eigenstate. However, I am unable to follow through with this calculation:

$$(a - a^t)e^{\frac{1}{2} a^ta^t} | 0 \rangle = ae^{\frac{1}{2} a^ta^t} | 0 \rangle - a^te^{\frac{1}{2} a^ta^t} | 0 \rangle = [a,e^{\frac{1}{2} a^ta^t}] | 0 \rangle - a^te^{\frac{1}{2} a^ta^t} | 0 \rangle = [a,e^{\frac{1}{2} a^ta^t}] | 0 \rangle = [a,a^ta^t]e^{\frac{1}{2}a^ta^t}| 0 \rangle = 2a^te^{\frac{1}{2}a^ta^t}| 0 \rangle $$

Where does this cancel out?

Comment: You assume $a^te^{\tfrac12a^ta^t}|0\rangle$ vanishes, but it's clearly a linear combination of states of odd particle number.

Comment: 1. What limit are you talking about here?  You have no parameter to take to the limit...  Do you mean $\lim_{\alpha\to\infty} e^{\frac{\alpha}{2}a^\dagger a^\dagger}\vert 0\rangle$?
 2. You have another problem that your state is not normalized so taking the limit is a delicate matter since the implicit normalization may itself become infinite in the limit...

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): $t$ should be $\dagger$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I may suggest another approach:

Defining $\left|-1\right\rangle$ as the zero vector,$$\begin{align}(a-a^\dagger)e^{\tfrac12a^ta^t}\left|0\right\rangle&=(a-a^\dagger)\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{\sqrt{(2n)!}}{n!2^n}\left|2n\right\rangle\\&=\sum_{n\ge0}\left(\frac{\sqrt{(2n)!}}{n!2^n}\sqrt{2n}\left|2n-1\right\rangle-\frac{\sqrt{(2n+1)!}}{n!2^n}\left|2n+1\right\rangle\right),\end{align}$$which you can show telescopes to $0$, using$$\frac{\sqrt{(2n)!}}{n!2^n}\sqrt{2n}=\frac{\sqrt{(2n-1)!}}{(n-1)!2^{n-1}}$$for $n\ge1$.